# Reduce or Increase looping depending on parameter input

Tags: java

I have an ArrayList which contains Strings with a size of 1000. I am looping through that ArrayList and finding words and trying to form a square from them. For example as follows:

```
C A R D
A R E A
R E A R
D A R T
```

It is working but it involves a lot of nested looping and I am hard-coding the loops in this instance where I am try to form a square 4x4.

I am looking to have the flexibility to pass in the square size for example 5x5 or 6x6 and so on and loop accordingly. How can I go about doing that.

If this was just a single loop, I would have just passed in an Integer and looped according to that Integer. But since I am nesting, the number of For loops needed is going to differ thus confused.

When I am forming a square of 4x4, I end up looping 4 times where each loops checks different substrings to derive a correct square. When 5x5 is needed, I would need 5 loops to make the checks. I mean to solve the issue where I increase decrease loops depending on the parameter/ or a way to loop without creating so many For Loops. Can I get some guidance on this please.

```
void makeWord(ArrayList<String> arr, int size){ //want to use this size to determine amount of loop

    String first, second, third, fourth;
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.size(); i++) {

        first = arr.get(i);

        for (int j = 0; j < arr.size(); j++) {
            if(first.substring(1,2).equals(arr.get(j).substring(0,1)) &&
                    (!first.equals(arr.get(j)))){
                second = arr.get(j);
            }
            else {
                second = "    ";
            }

            if (!second.trim().isEmpty()) {
                for (int k = 0; k < arr.size(); k++) {
                    if (first.substring(2, 3).equals(arr.get(k).substring(0, 1)) &&
                            second.substring(2, 3).equals(arr.get(k).substring(1, 2)) &&
                            (!first.equals(arr.get(k)) && (!second.equals(arr.get(k))))) {
                        third = arr.get(k);
                    } else {
                        third = "    ";
                    }


                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Not sure how nesting the for loops prevent you from passing an integer. Maybe try to take away non relevant details and focus your question on what it is you are tying to accomplish logic-wise

Comment: @ArtemioRamirez Edited the question. Removing the checks being performed is only going to start further questions on whats the point of those loops.

Comment: Break the problem up; one method to find the words, another to display them.

Comment: I have a feeling there is a rather simple answer to what it is that you want (reducing or increasing looping is not a hard thing) I just can't seem to understand the logic you are trying to achieve. The code inside the loops seems irrelevant to me, what you want is the loops to be executed in a certain way.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch Even if I split up those 2, when finding the words wouldn't I  still land with the issue of multiple for loops which depends on square size.

Comment: I suggest you start with [E. McCreight: A Space-Economical Suffix Tree Construction Algorithm](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.130.8022&rep=rep1&type=pdf).

Answer (score 0):

I am not completely sure if I got your question right, but if you are looking for a way to make your code more flexible so that you can build squares of any size, your main problem is the way you are storing the strings.

Since your loops depend on the number of strings you define, you limit yourself by hardcoding the string variables.
Alternatively you could simply store the text in an array matrix like so:

```
String[][] matrix = new String[size][size];
```

This allows you to build squares of any size and furthermore you do not need all those `substring()` calls anymore, what will supposingly increase performance, too.

Answer (score 0):

I think the following code snipped solves your issue:

```
public static void printSqaure(List<String> list, int size){
    for(int i=0; i< list.size(); i++){
        if(i <= size){
            String subStr = list.get(i).substring(0, size);
            System.out.println(subStr);
        }

    }
}
```